# Doctrine 2 how to index collections

Tags: indexing, collections, doctrine-orm, arraycollection

Can you explain me please, how to index Doctrine entity collections? I have an entity **Article** with collection of related **Categories** defined as **@ManyToMany** relationship. In this annotation I have parameter **indexBy="id"** which I hope creates an array of Categories indexed by its IDs. But the Categories collection is indexed like an php array from 0.
The code looks like:

```
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="articles", indexBy="id", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="articles_categories")
     */
    private $categories;
```

Can you tell me what am I doing wrong? THX.

Comment: Did you clean the cache?

Comment: Yes I did. Any other suggestions?